# What are good methods for save Java application data?

Tags: java, save

I'm new to Java and I was wondering what I should do to save small/medium amounts of data for a Java Application. I've heard about YAML but I'm not sure if that's my best choice. I'm just wondering how I should save small numbers, settings and even save files for simple games.

Comment: If the settings are name-value pairs you can use `Properties`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For really simple data storage needs you can just use the [java File Writer library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) for writing simple primitive data types to a file, then when you need to retrieve the data just use the [File Reader Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html). This is about as simple as you can get with storing data with java. If that is to simple, then I would suggest look at serializing your data objects and writing them to a file instead. Here's a [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-5things1/index.html), discusses the merits of object Serialization.

Answer (score 2):

If your traffic grows to larger amounts, consider using a database instead of a flat file. For small amounts you can use a flat file. Accipheran makes a good point to make sure you don't give your users access to things you want secure or hidden.

You don't have to use YAML, you can specify your own protocols depending on how much customization you need. But there are already libraries for YAML handling.

File IO: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaIO/article.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want save your objects, java serialisation is simpel to use. 
You get fast (by means of programming effort) and correct results.

For configuration input files i recommend java Property files.

For huge data, and cross plattfrom transfer java serialisation is less useable.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into serialisation.

Comment: Java serialisation is easier even for primitive files. It stays easy even for the very complex ones. Java makes that for you. If you finaly choosed serialisation the you could accept my answer again ;-)